# Why I am getting 404 not found error on installing using npm install @microsoft/microsoft-graph-client?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

```
npm install @microsoft/microsoft-graph-client --save
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found: @microsoft/microsoft-graph-client@^1.0.0
```

My Node version is v8.9.0 and my npm version is 5.1.0.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. It would be better if you checkout [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for future endeavor at Stack overflow.Great question tend to provide quicker, better answers from the community -Thank you

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I will consider for next question.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if it'll fix your problem in your case. But, it fixed mine, when i was fetching similar issue.

```
npm cache clean
npm rebuild
```

Then:

```
npm set registry https://registry.npmjs.org/
```

Comment: @MuhammadFarooq - I don't see any other issue, other then there is network issue.  Or, It is a Client-side Error which means that either the page has been removed or moved and the URL was not changed accordingly, or that you typed in the URL incorrectly. But, that is not the case, as i was to install it.